# Hot reloading glsl shaders

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, glsl

I have been spending a lot of times tweaking my shaders and I want to quickly reload a shader without recompiling my program. What is the official way to hot reload shaders in OpenGL 4.1?

Here is my current (non-functional) method:

Create a program pipeline, create one separable program per shader (right now it's just one vertex and one fragment) and use it in the pipeline. Load uniforms into each program that needs it (is there a way to mimic the old style of one uniform shared across shaders?)

```
glGenProgramPipelines(1, &programPipeline);
glBindProgramPipeline(programPipeline);   //is this necessary?

auto handle = glCreateShader(type);
const char* src = source.c_str();
glShaderSource(handle, 1, &src, NULL);
glCompileShader(handle);

program[idx] = glCreateProgram();
__glewProgramParameteri(program[idx], GL_PROGRAM_SEPARABLE, GL_TRUE); //xcode auto corrected this for me 
glAttachShader(program[idx], handle);
glLinkProgram(program[idx]);
glDetachShader(program[idx], handle);

glUseProgramStages(programPipeline, shaderStage,
                   program[idx]);
```

The part I am stuck at is what to do with attributes. It fails with "GL_INVALID_OPERATION" when I try to enable a vertex attrib array when in the normal non-separable programs it would work fine. I have generated and bound a vao and got the attrib location before trying to enable the vertex attrib array. The online resources I've found only mentions uniforms in conjunction with separable programs, but nothing regarding attributes. Can they even be used with separable programs? What would be the alternative?

Comment: you could use a uniform buffer and just bind that (while ensuring the layout remains the same

Comment: Changing to uniform still resulted in an invalid operation after the uniform operation. I rolled back to non-separable programs and rebuild both shaders and program when I want to hot-reload a shader.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong there. You could simplify it a bit by using [`glCreateShaderProgram`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glCreateShaderProgram.xhtml) which creates a separable program with a single shader. You absolutely can fetch attribute locations from separable programs.

If `glGetAttribLocation` isn't working, you could try using [`glGetProgramResourceIndex`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glGetProgramResourceIndex.xhtml) with `GL_PROGRAM_INPUT` as the program interface. They should perform the same operation but the driver might not follow this rule.